# Is there a way to get the annotation on a class using Smoke?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

Is there a way to get the annotation on a class using Smoke?

```dart
class Anno {
 const Anno();
}

@Anno
class A {
}

void main() {
  var a = new A();
  // how to get the annotation `@Anno` from `a` using the Smoke library
  someMethod(A);
}

var someMethod(Type t) {
  // get the annotation `@Anno` from `t` using the Smoke library
}
```

Comment: Would be easy with mirrors but it seems there is no equivalent to a class mirror in Smoke and no metadata whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. I know how to do it with mirrors but I want to ensure this gets converted to mirror-free code by the transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently any support for reading annotations in Smoke :(

You could raise an issue at [dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com), though I don't know whether it's likely the Polymer team will add functionality not required by Polymer ([my case](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20584) hasn't had any useful response) :(